# Error with set serveroutput on, PL/SQL script fails to execute in FME?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, fme

I am running a script in FME SQL Creator reader. Script looks like,

```
set serveroutput on
declare var1 a;
BEGIN dbms_output.enable(); dbms_output.put_line ('TEST LINE'); END;
```

Script runs successfully in Oracle SQL Developer. But If I run from FME, it returns nothing.

Comment: Probably FME lacks support for `dbms_output`. This seems like the sort of question you should be asking [on their community forum](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/index.html)

Comment: Thank for providing this link fro FME forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set serveroutput on and dbms_output.enable are oracle sql developer commands and not FME compatible or any other sql executor. So to return results from oracle database use functions on server side and call them from FME.